# ~(P&Q) derive to ~Pv~Q

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I would be grateful if someone could derive, by showing the proofs that:
 ~(P&Q) derives to ~Pv~Q.

The same derivation would be appreciated for |- [(P>Q)>P]>P

Comment: I assume you are using natural deduction.  What rules are you permitted to use? Are you required to use a specific proof checker that you could link to? Welcome! You might also want to search the "symbolic-logic" or "fitch" tag for similar proofs that are already available.

Comment: That’s correct, it is using natural deduction. We can use primitive and derived rules.

Comment: The first one would be DeMorgan Rule which is a derived rule, but perhaps you don't have that.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the time of day (night), I post only the first proof at this time.

A   = Assumption
vI  = v Introduction
&I  = & Introduction
RAA = Reductio Ad Absurdum
DN  = Double Negation

Feel free to ask about the reasoning behind all of this.

```
1   (1)     ~(P&Q)                  A
2   (2)     ~(~Pv~Q)                A
3   (3)     ~P                      A
3   (4)     ~P v ~Q                 3 vI
2,3 (5)     (~Pv~Q) & ~(~Pv~Q)      4,2 &I
2   (6)     ~~P                     3,5 RAA
2   (7)     P                       6 DN
8   (8)     ~Q                      A
8   (9)     ~Pv~Q                   8 vI
2,8 (10)    (~Pv~Q) & ~(~Pv~Q)      9,2 &I
2   (11)    ~~Q                     8,10 RAA
2   (12)    Q                       11 DN
2   (13)    P&Q                     7,12 &I
1,2 (14)    (P&Q) & ~(P&Q)          13,1 &I
1   (15)    ~~(~Pv~Q)               2,14 RAA
1   (16)    ~P v ~Q                 15 DN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to prove these using the following rules:

- Conjunction introduction (∧I)
- Contradiction introduction (⊥I)
- Negation introduction (¬I)
- Disjunction introduction (vI)
- Law of Excluded Middle (LEM)
- Reiteration (R)
- Conditional introduction (→I)
- Explosion (X)
- Conditional elimination (→E)

The first proof was provided in *forall x: Calgary Remix*, page 142, showing how to derive the DeMorgan rule.

[image]

This proof uses the law of excluded middle, as does the one above, by showing that both "P" and "¬P" when assumed derive the desired result.

[image]

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/